# Angular app with SSR: error 'Invalid token' from server

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

a have a problem: Angular app + ssr. Then user reload app, - get error in popup (mat-dialog) 'Invalid token'.
token get from cookie.
in network (DevTools) no errors.

**app.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    CookieModule.withOptions(),
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer, { metaReducers }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(rootEffects),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production }),
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    ErrorsPopupModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.server.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    CookieBackendModule.withOptions(),
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    ServerTransferStateModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {
}
```

**auth.guard.ts:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private _cookieService: CookieService,
    private _router: Router,
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    if (this._cookieService.get('token')) {
      console.log('authenticated!..');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('Not authenticated!');
      return this._router.createUrlTree(['auth']);
    }
  }
}
```

**auth.interceptor.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _cookieService: CookieService,
    private _errorsService: ErrorsService,) {
  }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this._cookieService.get('token');
    if (
      !req.url.includes('login')
      && !req.url.includes('restore_password')
      && !req.url.includes('verify')
      && !req.url.includes('register')
      && !req.url.includes('spheres')
    ) {
      if (token)
        return next.handle(req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            'Authorization': token,
          },
        })).pipe(
          catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log('intercept:', err);
            this._errorsService.openPopup(err)
            return []
          }));
    }
    return next.handle(req)

  }
}
```

App have  a SSR. Then html reneder without my mat-module (popup) - dialog doesnt work (methods for closing popup doesnt call)

Comment: But why are you using Bearer auth instead of Cookie auth+XSRF protection?

Comment: I don’t have an answer here) I got this project for revision. It was obvious that there was a problem with authorization, thanks for pointing out at this point!

Answer (score 0):

this post may be useful for the solution:
[send token to server in angular universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127096/send-token-to-server-in-angular-universal)

but we decided to abandon SSR in principle because of the uselessness of seo and potential memory leaks/
for example: [How to remove Angular Universal on angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508632/how-to-remove-angular-universal-on-angular-project)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).